# El servidor como verifica que el JWT de JwtTokenStore es valido o no ha expirado?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Yo hago uso de Spring Boot 1.5.9 y hago uso de la autenticacion con JWT por medio de la ruta **/oauth/token** y me ha servido totalmente bien pero siempre he tenido la duda de como o donde se quedan almacenado los tokens en el servidor 
por ejemplo si yo tengo 100.000 usuarios con tokens sin una expiracion limitada osea expires = 0 todos esos 100.000 tokens quedan guardados en algun almacenamiento del servidor?, en cache?, en memoria?, he leído de que el servidor verifica una firma, pero entonces la firma la tiene guardada en un lugar? osea no entiendo muy bien me gustaría que me ampliaran información sobre esto o me expliquen mejor, muchas gracias!!

Comment: La idel del jwt es que no se guarde , imagina esos 100,00 token almacenados? ocuparian espacio en tu disco sin motivo alguno,

Comment: Se guarda del lado del cliente. Está en la documentación.

Comment: Gracias, una pregunta pero como el servidor sabe si el token es valido y no lo han manipulado?, he leído que dicen que es por la firma que da el servidor pero osea la firma si queda guardada en el servidor y no se puede manipular o como funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servidor no guarda ni el token ni la firma en ningún lugar. La firma está contenida en el propio token. El formato de un token jwt consta de tres partes separadas por un punto (header.payload.firma), por ejemplo:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

Las partes son:

**header:** suele contener el tipo de token y el algoritmo usado. En este caso:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**payload:** contiene los datos que queremos almacenar en el token, por ejemplo fecha creación, fecha de caducidad, nivel de acceso o permisos y cualquier otro dato que queramos incluír para validar la petición. En este ejemplo:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

**firma:** la firma se consigue aplicando el algoritmo indicado en el header y con la  clave secreta, a los campos header y payload codificados en base64 y separados por un punto, tal que así:

```
HMACSHA256( base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload), your-256-bit-secret)
```

your-256-bit-secret es una clave privada y que no debe ser compartida con nadie.
Cuando el servidor recibe un token realiza aplica la misma fórmula comentada anteriormente al header y al payload. Si el resultado es el mismo que el contenido en el campo firma implica que el token se ha podido verificar, es correcto y no ha sido alterado. Si se altera alguno de los campos header o payload o la clave usada para verificar el token no es la correcta el resultado de la verificación será distinto y no coincidirá con el valor del campo firma del jwt. 
Se puede comprobar en la siguente página, alterando la clave secreta:

[jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c)

Por lo tanto, como se ve toda la información necesaria para verificar el token, salvo la clave privada, está contenida en el propio token.